# How does rails homepage works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have a Rails Website or Application
I have controllers for pages and posts
I want to create on my homepage section where I can see all pages and below that section for the posts
What is the common way to do that with the routes.rb? 
since I have two controller I don't know how to create the homepage

Answer (score 1):

To make your code more clear you can use separated controller for that. For example create `HomepageController` with action `home` and prepare all resources you need there:

```
class HomepageController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @pages = Page.where(....)
    @posts = Post.where(....)
  end
end
```

Create corresponding view file - `views/homepage/home.html.erb`

Then at the end of your routes.rb add:

```
root to: "homepage#home"
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'll try that